# Directory.GetFiles - different output dependent on OS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

I have a simple program. It runs .NET 4.5 and is built in Visual Studio 2013.

`D:\\MyDir` is full of `.xlsx` files and no `.xls` files. When I run the program on Windows 8.1 x64, the filter for `*.xls` returns no results. When I run the same program, with the same .NET version on Windows 7 x86, the `*.xls` filter returns the same results as the `*.xlsx` filter.

The test folders on both systems definitely contain the same data.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in .NET and/or Windows?

The respective code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace throw_test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int fileCount1 = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\MyDir", "*.xlsx").Length;
            int fileCount2 = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\MyDir", "*.xls").Length;

            Console.WriteLine("File Count 1: " + fileCount1);
            Console.WriteLine("File Count 2: " + fileCount2);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

When I navigate to the directory using the command prompt in Windows 8.1 x64:

- `dir *.xlsx` returns all files as expected
- `dir *.xls` returns 'File Not Found'

Windows 7 returns the expected files on both of the above commands.

My guess is that .NET uses this command under the hood, thus the above results?

Comment: Looks like a built-in Windows magic for application compatibility. Needs further investigation.

Comment: @ogggre its not any compatability for 8.1, its right in the MSDN for GetFiles "*... given two files, `file1.txt` and `file1.txtother`, in a directory, a search pattern of `file?.txt` returns just the first file, while a search pattern of `file*.txt` returns both files.*" his 8.1 machine is acting incorrectly and the results should have shown up.

Comment: I can't find the reference (I think it may have been a Raymond Chen post), but IIRC, this is a "feature" of old versions of Windows that goes back to the dos era.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You are right, tried on Windows 8.1 64-bit and the results are according to MSDN, the *.xls filter returns the same results as the *.xlsx filter.

Comment: Hmm... I think this was the article I was looking for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx ... but I doesn't discuss that particular quirk. It's talking about a whole other set of pattern oddities.

Comment: I guess you have disabled 8.3 naming. I added related info to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Windows 7 behavior is **by design**. From the [documentation on the GetFiles() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) (see the first note below the "Remarks" section):

> When using the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern, such as "*.txt", the matching behavior when the extension is exactly three characters long is different than when the extension is more or less than three characters long. A searchPattern with a file extension of exactly three characters returns files having an extension of three or more characters, where the first three characters match the file extension specified in the searchPattern. A searchPattern with a file extension of one, two, or more than three characters returns only files having extensions of exactly that length that match the file extension specified in the searchPattern.

The Windows 8.1 behavior is a **not reproducible** for me. I just ran a test on my Windows 8.1 x64 machine, and it matched the expected Windows 7 behavior. I would check that the current folder on the machine is correct.

I can also get the same results just by opening up a command prompt, navigating to the appropriate directory, and typing `dir *.xls`. I expect that both the GetFiles() function and the command prompt will pass the search pattern into the same low-level operating system function.

It's talking about some different issues, but this post is also worth a read:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx

Answer (score 7):

I tried on my machine with `*.xls` and all `xlsx` files are returned, just as described by [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx).

I have Visual Studio 2013, built as Debug/Release Any CPU on .NET 4.5, and run on Win 8.1 X64 against NTFS/FAT32 partition, should cover your environment. Do you have anything else special?

**EDIT**

According to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/235504/directory-search-in-windows-command-prompt-shows-incorrect-output/), you may have disabled 8.3 naming on your Win 8.1 System by running:

```
fsutil behavior set disable8dot3
```

You can query the current status by running

```
fsutil behavior query disable8dot3 <VolumePath>
```

On my machine it returns default setting like:

> The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled).
> The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).
>
> Based on the above two settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on c: