# C# Directory.GetFiles returns different result on different computer

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I just noticed a very weird thing in my application. I have a snippet of code that checks if a folder or any sub folder contains `.xls` files instead of `.xlsx`. This is because I use `EPPlus` which can't handle `.xls` files. On a computer running `Windows 10 Home` the code below only returns `.xls` files but not any `.xlsx` files. I now tried to run the same code on a `Windows 10 Pro` machine and the code picked up `.xlsx` files as well. I know I can get only `.xls` files using `Linq`  but I still would like to know why this can happen.

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\xmlfiles", "*.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

if (filePaths.Count > 0)
{
    var files = string.Join(",", filePaths);
    throw new Exception($"Folder contains .xls files which EPPlus can't handle. Please convert them first. Files: {files}");
}
```

Comment: Wild guess here, but I think the underlying FileSystem API must be returning the XLSX files as well(bug parsing the regex could be a reason)

Comment: FYI: on Win10 Enterprise xslx do get picked up too with your snippet

Comment: So this is expected behavior. The question now should be, why does it work differently on win 10 home?

Comment: You should query your results after retrieving files from the patternt "*.xls"

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

When you use the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern such as "*.txt", the number of characters in the specified extension affects the search as follows:

- If the specified extension is exactly three characters long, the
  method returns files with extensions that begin with the specified
  extension. For example, **"*.xls"** returns both **"book.xls"** and
  **"book.xlsx"**.
- In all other cases, the method returns files that       exactly match
  the specified extension. For example, "*.ai" returns       "file.ai"
  but not "file.aif".

When you use the question mark wildcard character, this method returns only files that match the specified file extension. For example, given two files, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", in a directory, a search pattern of "file?.txt" returns just the first file, whereas a search pattern of "file*.txt" returns both files.

**Above is normal behaviour as MSDN says.**

But on your question it may cause from filename convention [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename). Disable it and look if you get the result as expected.

```
fsutil behavior set disable8dot3
```

Also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20320447/2794280)

Comment: This explains the "normal" behavior, but not why it is different on Windows 10 Home. How does the above, in any way, answer the _question_? And why would you post two answers and delete one, instead of just editing the first answer?

Comment: Doesn't really answer his questions for the difference between Home and Pro

Comment: Windows 10 Home is a rebadged Vista